# c# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error code : 0x800a03ec cannot access file

Tags: c#

Here i am trying to save excel file at specific path using COM.
In a local server it is working but when I user IIS server to run asp.net web application it is showing an error message as per heading.

```
string selected_sheet = 
DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Remove(DropDownList1.SelectedValue.IndexOf("$"));            
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Data/");
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(path + selected_sheet);
```

Comment: what about `~/Data/test.xlsx`

Comment: For the first time it is saved on that location but second time I need to overwrite file but it is showing same error.

Comment: so it is partly solved?

Comment: In visual studio server it was working till here, but in IIS server yes problem  partially solved.

Comment: did you ever close the excel application(not in your posted code)?